# If I include Prototype and jQuery, why does inline jQuery conflict (over use of $) but not included jQuery files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict

If Prototype is included in the page already, I have to do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
```

for inline jQuery scripts instead of this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
```

But if I have an included jQuery file on the same page that uses `$`, that does not seem to conflict, e.g.:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/included.js'></script>
```

In other words, I don't have to edit `included.js` and change all of the `$` to `jQuery`.

Why the distinction: included files versus inline scripts?

Answer (score 3):

included may be playing safe and deliberately shadowing $

```
(function($) {
  // included.js code here
})(jQuery);
```